# Why does js oscillators stop playing sound after some use?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio

I'm trying to make a simple piano with js but I don't want to use audio samples, instead I want to generate sound programmatically. To play single sound I am using this code from this blog https://marcgg.com/blog/2016/11/01/javascript-audio/

```
var context = new AudioContext()
var o = context.createOscillator()
var  g = context.createGain()
o.connect(g)
g.connect(context.destination)
o.start(0)
g.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.00001, context.currentTime + 5)
```

I found that after playing it more than about 50 times this method stops working. No sound plays when running this code, `context.currentTime` does not change and stays 0. How can I fix it without stopping already playing sound?

Comment: almost assuredly needs more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new `AudioContext` for each note; create one and use it for all of them. This will not only save resources; it will also help with playing multiple notes at precise times if you decide you want to do that.

You're also accumulating oscillators that are still playing, just extremely quietly. You need to stop them *sometime*. The good news is, the Web Audio API is designed to [make it easy to do this:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/stop)

```
// stop after 5 seconds from now
o.stop(context.currentTime + 5);
```